# How do I avoid continious reapiring of my file?

Tags: excel

I have an excel as described in my other posts. There are a few macros in it. It keeps prompting me for repairs, and I repair them. However, the error message is weird, as it refers to a sheet1, which I do not have.

[image]

the details read:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

-<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">

<logFileName>error099480_01.xml</logFileName>

<summary>Der blev fundet fejl i filen 'C:\Users\anjsk\Documents\projekter\Sygekort\Elektronisk Fraværsark_Template v.1.xlsm'</summary>


-<removedRecords>

<removedRecord>Fjernede poster: Sortering fra /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml-del</removedRecord>

</removedRecords>

</recoveryLog>
```

I find it rather strange that I keep getting this error, since I do not have a `sheet1`...

Hope someone can help, as I cannot send this out to users with errors like this...

My sorting code:

```vb
With ActiveSheet.Sort
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("d4"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortTextAsNumbers
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("a4"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortTextAsNumbers
     .SetRange Range("a5:ai" & lrow)
     .Header = xlYes
     .Apply
End With
```

Comment: In `Office Open XML` `/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml` is the internal storage of the first worksheet independent of it's name. **Every** `*.xlsx` or `*.xlsm` workbook has that. And the error points to a problem with the sorting settings in that first worksheet. But that means that something (`VBA` or another program?)  changes something in the sorting settings of the first worksheet. And it does it wrong and on a very low level, so it leads to an error in the `XML` storage of the worksheet.

Comment: Aaahhh! Makes sense, since I have moved my coded pane to position one. (used to be error in sheet 3 :-) ) 
What do you mean witht the "...wrong and on a very low level.."??

Comment: Hmm, I made the VBA code to the sorting by making a macro.It loks like this
`With ActiveSheet.Sort
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("d4"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortTextAsNumbers
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("a4"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortTextAsNumbers
     .SetRange Range("a5:ai" & lrow)
     .Header = xlYes
     .Apply
End With`

Guess I would need to change to more VBA-like format. But why should it need repairing just because it is macro "format".The code works...

Comment: Code in Comments is not readable and useless as such. As said, a program changes sorting settings on a level where normal user activities won't. And it does it wrong, so it leads to a corrupted internal `XML` storage of that worksheet. Normally `VBA` code cannot lead to such problems as it only automates the `GUI` and so only does what a user also could do. Hard to say what happens whitout having the whole workbook.

Comment: Your code should be clearing existing sort fields before it adds new ones. That is the most common cause of the error you are seeing.

Comment: @Rory: Indeed. Normal `VBA` code is able corrupting the `Excel` file as it is able adding multiple sort fields having the same key. I would call this a bug as this normally gets avoided using the `GUI`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think it is because I use the keys in row 4, and set the range from row 5 - and says yes to headers. That is inconsistent.

Have changed the range to include the headers.

Comment: No, this is **not** the problem. The problem is that your code adds multiple sort fields having the same key if it gets runned multiple times. You should add `.SortFields.Clear` before first `.SortFields.Add` as @Rory said. So credit would go to @Rory.